# openstack octavia loadbalancing

Tags: networking, load-balancing, openstack, openstack-neutron

I use Openstack Victoria on Ubuntu OS. in Openstack docs say that in neutron.conf file we must add following lines: `service_plugins = [existing service plugins],neutron_lbaas.services.loadbalancer.plugin.LoadBalancerPluginv2` and `service_provider = LOADBALANCERV2:Octavia:neutron_lbaas.drivers.octavia.driver.OctaviaDriver:default` im okay with second option, but with first option my neutron service cant find this! also without them, when i create a loadbalancer its active but is offline and amphora port is active but lb port is down! Are there related?

means in neutron server logs show this error: `ERROR neutron_lib.utils.runtime [req-c67e9c5d-e62c-4c14-a686-2b9bcf141725 - - - - -] Error loading class by alias: stevedore.exception.NoMatches: No 'neutron.service_plugins' driver found, looking for 'LOADBALANCERV2:Octavia:neutron_lbaas.drivers.octavia.driver.OctaviaDriver:default'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neutron LBaaS was removed from OpenStack in Train, so trying to add the provider for Octavia in Neutron won't work, and it isn't needed for Octavia to work.

You most likely need to look at the Octavia logs to figure out why your load balancers aren't working.

Comment: thnx... I checked ,but I have no errors in related log file... even I checked amphora server logs and have not any error! just in ```systemctl stataus amphora-agent```  it say ```setting key "net.ipv4.conf.all.promote_secondaries": Invalid argument``` and in ```/var/log/octavia/amphora-agent.log``` not exist any error!

Comment: also in ```octavia-helth-manager``` logs i have just this warning: ```WARNING octavia.amphorae.drivers.health.heartbeat_udp [-] Health Manager experienced an exception processing a heartbeat message from ('172.20.91.212', 51366). Ignoring this packet. Exception: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'```

Comment: also when I create a pool and assign my nodes as members, it work but show offline, means if make nodes to sample server and use ```curl loadbalancer_ip``` it show truly nodes!

Comment: Do you have `heartbeat_key` set under `health_manager` in `octavia.conf`? It can be set to any string, e.g. `change me later`.

Comment: no I didnt set! Is it nessesary? because in openstack doc did not saied anything!

Comment: I set that, now... my warnings are resolved, but my LB is yet offline! :|